# How to implement SSL/TLS into a Spring Boot Rest server and JavaFX client?

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl, apache-commons-httpclient

I am making a program all written in Java. Server is Spring Boot RESTful and client is an desktop app made with JavaFX that uses Apache HttpClient library to communicate to the server. Now I need to secure it with SSL/TLS. I am interested in the implementation itself and also whether a self signed certificate is enough since the program will be used only in LAN.